# How do I replace bootloader to grub from mbr?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows

I want the system to boot directly into ubuntu.

I have tried the solution:

1. [How to set grub as the boot manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923136/how-to-set-grub-as-the-boot-manager)
2. [Remove windows boot manager and use grub instead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882724/remove-windows-boot-manager-and-use-grub-instead)
3. [How to get GRUB to be the default bootloader instead of Windows Boot Manager on a UEFI laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-to-get-grub-to-be-the-default-bootloader-instead-of-windows-boot-manager-on)
4. https://superuser.com/questions/1247300/how-to-make-uefi-bios-start-grub-not-windows

but I failed.

I have dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Now its booting into windows 10 if I don't press any key.

I want it to boot the system to Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the process you followed, trying to dual boot. At least the order of installation (eg. ubuntu first, then windows)

Comment: Windows 10 first and then ubuntu.